# When write in action HttpPostedFileBase[] fileName return Null

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

**In Html Page I write**

```
 <form  name="memForm" id="memForm" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="PublishCourse" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button id="btnMore">More</button>
    <input type="file" name="axaisLogos[]" class="file custom-file-upload-hidden required" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File/Files"/>
    </form>
```

**at the Server Side in the Controller I write as the follow**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PublishCourse(HttpPostedFileBase[] axaisLogos)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

*too try like this*

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PublishCourse( IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> axaisLogos)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

*too try like this*

```
 public ActionResult PublishCourse(List<HttpPostedFileBase> axaisLogos)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**but all these ways return null .**

*Developers please Help me .*

Comment: Too when put break point at the PublishCourse Action then go to html page when mouse hover on the name="axaisLogos[]" property show null too

Comment: input name should not include `[]`

Comment: `name="axaisLogos"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` attribute of `input` tag should not include `[]`

```
<input type="file" name="axaisLogos" class="file custom-file-upload-hidden required" />
```

It should now work for all the example actions shown in your controller.

Comment: but why when  use name property as the arrays with input text type it's not return null like that write <input name="axaisNames[]" type="text" />  this well run